# Selenium webdriver: How to find nested tags?

Tags: ruby, selenium

A webpage contains

```
<div class="divclass">
 <ul>
  <li>
   <a href="www.abc1.com">"hello world 1"</a>
   <img src="abc1.jpg">
  </li>
  <li>
   <a href="www.abc2.com">"hello world 2"</a>
   <img src="abc2.jpg">
  </li>
 </ul>
</div>
```

I am able to get data under div using

```
element = driver.find_element(class: "divclass")
element.text.split("\n")
```

But I want all links respective to the achieved data

I tried using

```
driver.find_elements(:css, "div.divclass a").map(&:text)
```

but failed. 
How can I get related links to the data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to get the href attribute try the below code(I am not familiar with ruby so I am posting the code in Java).

```
List<WebElement> elements = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//*[@class='divclass']//a"));
    for(WebElement webElement:elements){        
    System.out.println(webElement.getAttribute("href"));
    }
```

The xpath points to all the a tags under the div tag with class name =divclass.
If you want to get the text of all the links, you can use the blow code:

```
  List<WebElement> elements = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//*[@class='divclass']//a"));
    for(WebElement webElement:elements){        
    System.out.println(webElement.getText());
    }
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

In ruby

```
element = driver.find_elements(:xpath, "//*[@class='divclass']//a")
list = element.collect{|e| hash ={e.text => e.attribute("href")}}
```

will return corresponding links with data in array of hashes